# django rest framework max_lenght CharField issue

Tags: django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a serializer to show a list of products in api_view. this list will include 3 things from my product model( their title, id, price). i use CharField for title with max_lenght=255 but i get and innit unknown_kwarg error for it. any solotions?

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6,
        decimal_places=2,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    inventory = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    promotions = models.ManyToManyField(Promotion, blank=True)
```

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    title = serializers.CharField()
    unit_price = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

```
  File "E:\python learning\storefront2\store\views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .serializers import ProductSerializer
  File "E:\python learning\storefront2\store\serializers.py", line 3, in <module>
    class ProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  File "E:\python learning\storefront2\store\serializers.py", line 5, in ProductSerializer
    title = serializers.CharField(max_lenght=254)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\storefront2-EzF46c-9\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 730, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: Field.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_lenght'
```

After removing max_lenght, everything will work just fine!

Comment: It must `max_length` please. You have typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a typo : <s>`max_lenght`</s> -> `max_length`

```py
title = serializers.CharField(max_length=254)
                                    ^^
```